# How to use Splitter with Aggregate using xml in Apache Camel 3.20.0

Tags: apache-camel

I want to split Json array containing 100 Json objects using splitter and send it as a group of 10 json objects to next route

I am using Apache camel 3.20.0

This is what i tried

```
<route>
    < from uri : splitter>
    <split>
        <jsonpath>$</jsonpath>
        <aggregate aggregationStrategy= org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy
                   completionSize="10" completionTimeout="1000">
            <correlationExpression>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </correlationExpression>
            <marshal>
                <json></json>
            </marshal>
        </aggregate
    </split>
    < to uri : transformer>
</route>
```

But this is giving me error

> can not find aggregation strategy in registry with name: org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy.

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Camel "aggregationStrategy" attribute has to be the name of a registered bean, and not the bean classname.

Example of correct use:

```
<bean id="myStrategy" class="org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy"/>

<camelContext>
    <route>
        <from uri="..."/>
        ...
        <aggregate aggregationStrategy="myStrategy">
          
        </aggregate>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: Hi ,
After using attribute has to be the name of a registered bean below error is resolved

can not find aggregation strategy in registry with name: org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy

But it is not able to split in batches it is splitting in batches of 1 only

 <aggregate aggregationStrategy= "myStrategy"  completionSize="10" completionTimeout="1000">

completionSize="10" it is not taking into consideration, can u pls suggest on this